# LibGdx How to make a sound play only at start of overlap between Actors?

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I'm trying to make an Ouch! sound play at only the start of an overlap between a ball and wall Actors. So if the overlap is maintained I don't want the sound to play unless actors stop overlapping and then overlap again.

Here is part of the code where I'm trying to play the ouch sound:

```
for (BaseActor wallActor : BaseActor.getList(mainStage, "com.mygdx.game.WallBlock")){
        ball.preventOverlap(wallActor);

        ouch.play();
    }
```

Please provide an example of how I could make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't posted much code but the solution is simple, keep a boolean overlapping in your ball actor and only when it changes from false to true play the sound.

Pseudocode:

```java
public class Ball
{
    private boolean overlapping;
    private YourGame game; //could be a screen too or simply a world object
    // other ball fields ...


    public void update()
    {
        boolean wasOverlapping = overlapping;
        overlapping = isOverlapping();

        if(!wasOverlapping && overlapping)
            ouch.play();

        if(!overlapping && wasOverlapping)
        {
            //you could also play a sound when it stops overlapping here!
        }
    }

    private boolean isOverlapping()
    {
        for(Wall wall : game.getWalls())
        {
            if(wall.overlap(this)) //this refers to the ball
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```